# Dedicated controller? How to structure admin feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it better to extend my users controller to include administrative task on other nested controllers?

Or create a 'profile' controller where I could create different actions and views that summarize admin actions.

Scenario A:

**"/users/current/"** : would show a  link to edit products user own.

**"/users/current/products"** - Products controller would detect if it is accessed as a nested ressources.  If so, would show all user products and edit links to product.  In that case, the view would have to be completely different if it is access as nested ressource or not.

Scenario B:

**"/profile/"** : would show a  link to edit products user own.

**"profile/products"** : products would be an action in profile controller that show all products own by the user with links to edit those products on products controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do find it helpful to separate admin actions from a end-user actions, so I would lean towards the "/profile/" scenario.

But really, it's a matter of personal taste. Just decide which structure you'll most easily recognize in 6 months, when you've forgotten where everything is. Also take into consideration which structure will become less cluttered if you should ever start adding more features (actions) to those controllers.